# DB2 Datasource configuration - CXF, JBoss 6, Spring

Tags: spring, web-services, jboss, db2, datasource

Currently, I have a data source declaration in my CXF.xml.

```
<bean id="myDB2DataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="<my db2 url>" />
    <property name="username" value="<my username>" /> 
    <property name="password" value="<my password>" />
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="blockingReadConnectionTimeout">20</prop>
        </props>                                  
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works well. But I need to move this to my datasource xml file (my-ds.xml) using probably JNDI.

something like:
(in cxf.xml)

```
<bean id="myDB2DataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/jdbc.datasource.myDB2DataSource</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and (in my-ds.xml):

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc.datasource.myDB2DataSource"
    pool-name="jdbc.datasource.myDB2DataSource" jta="false">
    <connection-url>"<my db2 url>"
    </connection-url>
    <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name><my username></user-name>
        <password><my password></password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

But I can't make it work. What should be the correct config in cxf.xml and my-ds.xml?

I always encounter BeanCreationNotAllowedException. : Error creating bean with name 'cxf'

And many other exceptions which I believe caused by this since my bean myDB2DataSource can't be found ().

```
No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=myDB2DataSource)}

Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceMIMS' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc.datasource.myDB2DataSource -- service jboss.naming.context.java."jdbc.datasource.myDB2DataSource"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does it fail? Do you see your datasource in jboss console? Any errors in the jboss log during startup?

Comment: Please clarify, what doesn't work? Exceptions, stacktraces..